# How to build an exception class that reports which file and line numbers in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, error-handling

## The problem

I'm trying to build an `Exception` class that I can derive from to `throw` errors that report helpful information, like line number and file of origin.

## The code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;


class Exception : public std::logic_error {
    const char *msg;
    std::string line;
    std::string file;

    std::string build_exception() const {
        std::ostringstream stream;
        stream << file << ":" << line << ": " << msg << std::endl;
        return stream.str();
    }

public:
    explicit Exception(const char *msg) : msg(""), std::logic_error(build_exception()) {};

    Exception(const char *msg, const std::string &file, int line) :
            msg(msg),
            std::logic_error(build_exception()) {}

    ~Exception() noexcept override = default;

    Exception(Exception const &other) noexcept(true): msg(other.msg), logic_error(build_exception()) {};

    Exception &operator=(Exception const &other) = default;

    const char *what() const noexcept override {
        return build_exception().c_str();
    }

};


class AnotherError : public Exception {
public:
    using Exception::Exception;
};


int main() {

    throw AnotherError("with this message ", __FILE__, __LINE__);
    return 0;
};
```

## Current Output

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'AnotherError'
  what():  :: with this message
```

## Desired output

I want the `AnotherError` object to be thrown with the message `<filename>:<line_number>: with this message`

Comment: While not in the standard, there is [`boost::stacktrace`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/stacktrace/getting_started.html) that provides this capability.

Comment: Where in `Exception(const char *msg, const std::string &file, int line) :
            msg(msg),
            std::logic_error(build_exception()) {}` do you initialize `file` or `line` that `build_exception()` uses?

Comment: You don't save the file & line information in `Exception` constructor: `Exception(const char *msg, const std::string &file, int line) : msg(msg), std::logic_error(build_exception()) {}`

Comment: If your compiler suuports it you may find [std::source_location](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location) useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function:

```
const char *what() const noexcept override {
    return build_exception().c_str();
}
```

leads to UB as you return a dangling pointer (you call `c_str()` on a temporary `std::string`, which get destroyed at the end of expression). Also you are missing code in your constructor which sets members `file` and `line`.

I believe easiest solution would be to store `std::string` with the error message inside this class (and you would not need to store `msg`, `file` and `line` separately). On the other hand, if you want just to use `std::logic_error` to provide error message you should remove the override of virtual function `what()`:

```
class Exception : public std::logic_error {
    static std::string build_exception( const char *msg, const char *file = "", int line = 0 )  {
        std::ostringstream stream;
        stream << file << ":" << line << ": " << msg << std::endl;
        return stream.str();
    }

public:
    explicit Exception(const char *msg) std::logic_error(build_exception(msg)) {};

    Exception(const char *msg, const char *file, int line) :
            std::logic_error(build_exception(msg,file,line)) {}
};
```